# How can I run docker container without entering into container

Tags: bash, docker

I have Dockefile

```
FROM centos:7
```

So I have no entrypoint in dockerfile.
Then I build it to image

```
sudo docker build -t my_container .
```

Then I start it.

```
sudo docker run -t my_container
```

And I get open tty to container

```
root@my_container_id/
```

If I start it without `-t` it stopped immidiately after start.
How can I run docker container without start tty and without entrypoint?

Comment: What is your point? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to learn how to run a container from image, do nothing (not execute script and not run any program) and leave this container running. I want to get docker command for this goals.

Comment: Try `docker run -it ubuntu sleep infinity`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can start your container in a [*detached* mode](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cli/#examples):

```
docker run -it -d my_container
```

The `-d` option here means your container will run in "detached" mode, in the background.

If you want to [attach](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/attach/#extended-description) the container and drop to a shell, you can use:

```
docker exec -it my_container /bin/bash
```

Note, if your container is based on an alpine image, you need to use `sh`, i.e.:

```
docker exec -it my_container /bin/sh
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that. Your container lives if its main process is running, so you have to have a main process which is the process with PID 1 inside your container, and your container will be up if that process is running.