# Is there anyway to start docker container without a service?

Tags: php, docker, containers

I have a php container which needs php-fpm to be started everytime I start the container . Now because of a wrong configuration in php-fpm config file , fpm does not gets started and so , container cannot start. Is there anyway that I can start the container without php-fpm so that I can fix the config file?
The container error is as follows :

```
[04-Sep-2020 13:47:30] ERROR: [/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.conf:7] value is NULL for a ZEND_INI_PARSER_ENTRY

[04-Sep-2020 13:47:30] ERROR: failed to load configuration file '/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.conf'

[04-Sep-2020 13:47:30] ERROR: FPM initialization failed
```

Comment: I would normally recreate the container with the correct file copied into the container.  This means that when I need to copy or delete the container the process I use works without manual changes needed.

Comment: Thanks for your comment , but isn't there any way other than re-creating the container?

Comment: Perhaps some of the info on https://stackoverflow.com/a/43494442/1213708 may help to get to a shell in the container.

Comment: How are you starting the container now?  What image is is based on?  You can override the main container command at startup time (for example, to get an interactive debugging shell).

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks for your comment , digitalocean/php is the image , as the container does not start , how can I get into a debugging shell?

Comment: Make the main container command be `bash` or `sh`, instead of the `php-fpm` default from the image.  How are you starting the container now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to fix the image. Since I can't find image `digitalocean/php`, I'll use `php:7.4-fpm` in my example.

First way:
Copy file from the container and use it to build your own image:

Create Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm

COPY ./php-fpm.conf /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.conf
```

Then:

```
docker run --detach --name php php:7.4-fpm tail -f /dev/null
docker cp php:/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.conf php-fpm.conf
docker stop php
docker rm -v php
# Edit php-fpm.conf
docker build --tag myphp-fm .
docker run --detach --name php myphp-fpm
```

and you get running container based on the fixed image.

---

Second way:

Run a shell using the broken image, fix the file and create a new image using the shell container

```
docker run -it --name php php:7.4-fpm bash
# Edit /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.conf
# If you install any additional tools remember to remove them afterwards
# and clean any cache's
# Once you're done exit the shell, thus stopping the container
docker commit -a "you" -m "/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.conf fix" php myphp-fpm
docker stop php
docker rm -v php
docker run --detach --name php myphp-fpm
```

and again you get running container based on the fixed image.

---

Of course, you can run your new image in whatever way you run the original image in the beginning.

I recommend the first way as it's way easier to edit the file outside the container.